# C - Sorting a Copy of a Struct* Array Inside of a function

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc

```
struct numz
{
  int num;
};

typedef struct numz_ numz;

int main()
{
  int num_elements = 10;
  numz* myStruct_a = smalloc(sizeof(int)*num_elements;

  for (n = 0; n < num_elements; n++)
    myStruct_a->num[n] = n;

  funct(myStruct_a);

  return 0;
}

numz *funct(numz *myStruct_a)
{
  int num_elements = 10;
  numz* myStruct_a_cpy = smalloc(sizeof(int)*num_elements;

  for (n = 0; n < num_elements; n++)
  {
    myStruct_a_cpy->num[n] = myStruct_a->num[n];
  }

  //PSEUDO CODE
  //REARRANGE THE ELEMENTS IN myStruct_a_cpy

  return myStruct_a_cpy;
}
```

Why is `myStruct_a_cpy` not rearranged?

Comment: I dont see where you rearrange the elements. I only see the comment marking where you are supposed to.

Comment: Because you commented out the code that rearranges it? What makes you think it isn't rearranged in your real code, since you never print it out or otherwise test whether `myStruct_a_cpy` is different from `myStruct_a`? Show some code that actually has the problem.

Comment: That code is riddled with errors and wouldn't compile on the best of days.

Comment: You need to provide more code, and correct the mistakes in the code you've provided. There are missing semi-colons and parenthesis.

Comment: This can hardly be your real code, as it is riddled with errors and can't compile, and exactly the code that is apparently not working is commented out, so it is impossible to tell what is wrong. Post your real code.

Comment: The code and question itself is bogus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why are you initializing `myStruct_a_cpy` with `smalloc(sizeof(int)*num_elements)`? shouldn't it be `sizeof(myStruct)`?

Also, why not just use qsort?

int compare(const void * a, const void * b)
{
      myStruct * struct_a = (myStruct*) a;
      myStruct * struct_b = (myStruct*) b;
      // compare the contents of the two structs,
      // return -1 if a < b, 1 if a > b, and 0 otherwise.
}

myStruct *funct(myStruct *myStruct_a)

```
{
    int num_elements = 10;
    myStruct* myStruct_a_cpy = smalloc(sizeof(int)*num_elements);
    for (n = 0; n < num_elements; n++)
    {
        myStruct_a_cpy[n] = myStruct_a[n]
    }
    qsort(myStruct_a_cpy, 10, sizeof(myStruct), compare);
}
```